# How I can fix the following error in replication RDF in virtuoso OpenSource?

Tags: replication, virtuoso

I'm trying to do replication RDF triples in Virtuoso, but I have an error when connecting with the `pulbicador` server via `repl_server`. `function ()` says:

```
Error 42S22: [OpenLink] [Virtuoso ODBC Driver] [Virtuoso Server] 
SR242: No system status variable st_repl_server_enable
```

Please help with this error.

Comment: Please show us some code. What did you find after googling?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use a feature of the [Commercial Edition, but you're running the Open Source Edition](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/features-comparison-matrix/).

Comment: Thank you
Now I installed the commercial version available up to 15 days free, but when I do replicaciónn I get the following error: Error 08004:[OpenLink] [Virtuoso ODBC Driver] [Virtuoso Server]LI101: Application access not licensed

Maybe you know something about it???

Comment: This is not an appropriate topic/thread for StackOverflow, a programming assistance site. Apparently, the license file you're using doesn't permit the feature you are trying to use.  Please use our company resources - email our sales team, mailto:sales@openlinksw.com, or post to our [public support forums](http://boards.openlinksw.com/support/index.php) or open a [confidential support case](http://support.openlinksw.com/support/online-support.vsp).

Comment: Ok
I just sent an email to: sales@openlinksw.com
I wait your answer

Thank you